# Deploying the custom settings and accessing classes to Prod

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a custom setting(list) with a custom field, which is accessed in the apex class in the sandbox. When I deploy the custom setting, custom field, apex class and test class to the Production, the validation fails with the error message : Attempt to de-reference a null object. And this error points the line number where there is a getInstance method to access the data in the custom setting. So do I have deploy the custom setting and custom field first, create the data and then deploy the apex class and test class. Is there any better way of handling this? Thanks.

Comment: Does your test method create a record in your Custom Setting?

Comment: Sounds like your tests are `SeeAllData` and counting on the Custom Settings existing already. If you really can't fix the test, you could deploy just the Custom Setting first, populate it, then deploy the class and test.

Comment: But you should really fix the test.

Comment: Benj and Andrian The test class doesn't create a record.  I've used SeeAllData in the test class. So to fix the test class, I think I need to create a record in the custom setting, rather than using SeeAllData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an `API Version` above `23.0`, your test will default to `SeeAllData=false`. Therefore you need to create your own data. Note that `Custom Settings` need to be inserted by a `System Administrator`.

```
@IsTest
class MyTestClass
{
    static final String INSTANCE_NAME = 'testData';
    static final String CUSTOM_URL = 'www.sampleurl.com';

    static User ADMIN_USER
    { // this should be in a public test utility somewhere
        get
        {
            if (ADMIN_USER == null)
            {
                ADMIN_USER = [
                    SELECT Id FROM User
                    WHERE IsActive = true
                    AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
                    LIMIT 1
                ];
            }
            return ADMIN_USER;
        }
        set;
    }

    static void setupCustomSetting()
    {
        My_Custom_Setting__c customSetting = new My_Custom_Setting__c();
        customSetting.MyCustomField__c = 'www.sampleurl.com';
        system.runAs(ADMIN_USER)
        {
            insert customSetting;
        }
    }

    static testMethod void testMyMethod()
    {
        setupCustomSetting();

        Test.startTest();
            My_Custom_Setting__c instance = My_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance(INSTANCE_NAME);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertNotEquals(null, instance);
        system.assertEquals(CUSTOM_URL, instance.MyCustomField__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say, My_Custom_Setting__c has a custom field mycustomfield__c. There is one data with Name as 'testdata' and mycustomfield__c as an 'www.sampleurl.com' url. In the apex class, we get the instance --> String strCustomUrl = My_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance('testdata').mycustomfield__c; So in the test class you've given, we are inserting the custom setting. How to insert the field and data.

Comment: I updated my answer to try to better address your needs.